# "The requested address is not valid in its context" SocketException

Tags: c#, socketexception

I'm trying to send a broadcast packet (dest: FF.FF.FF.FF) to the local network on port 45624, except that an exception is being thrown when the UdpClient is created. I've tried this with other addresses, including ones which aren't actually subnet masks, but it always raises that exception. Ditto for ports other than 45624.

```
byte[] SearchAddr = new byte[] { 255, 255, 255, 255 };
IPAddress SearchIP = new IPAddress(SearchAddr);
IPEndPoint EndPoint = new IPEndPoint(SearchIP, 45624);
UdpClient Searcher = new UdpClient(EndPoint);
byte[] SearchPacket = new byte[] { 0x34, 0x00, 0xB0, 0xFA, 0x02, 0x00, 0x08, 0xFC, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x70, 0x6C, 0x61, 0x79, 0x02, 0x00, 0x0E, 0x00, 0x20, 0x74, 0x79, 0x99,
    0xF5, 0xF5, 0xCF, 0x11, 0x98, 0x27, 0x00, 0xA0, 0x24, 0x14, 0x96, 0xC8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x81, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
Searcher.Send(SearchPacket, SearchPacket.Length);
byte[] SearchReply = Searcher.Receive(ref EndPoint);
string ReplyText = "";
for (int I = 0; I < SearchReply.Length; I++)
    ReplyText += SearchReply[I].ToString("X2") + " ";
MessageBox.Show(ReplyText);
```

Does anyone know what, exactly, the problem is?

Comment: More details needed. Include the socket exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for [`UdpClient.Send`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/08h8s12k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) sheds light on the issue:

> This overload sends datagrams to the remote host established in the
>   `Connect` method and returns the number of bytes sent. If you do not
>   call `Connect` before calling this overload, the `Send` method will throw
>   a `SocketException`.

You should use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82dxxas0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead:

```
Searcher.Send(SearchPacket, SearchPacket.Length, EndPoint);
```

Comment: That fixed the exception, thanks! Now I have to figure out how to mark the question as answered.

Comment: @user2041202: Click the check mark below the answer vote count. I think new users have to wait a minimum amount of time (15 minutes?) before being able to accept an answer.